# Deleting more than 1 entry from a checkbox php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Ive used the following code to delete and array of checkboxes from another page written in php but I can only delete 1 entry at a time

```
<?php
    $checked = "";
    $status  = (isset($_REQUEST['status'])); //Checks if any checkboxes have been selected
    if ($status == 'checked') {
        $status  = 1;
        $checked = 'checked="checked"'; 

        $value = $_POST['status']; //Uses the value of the checkbox

        foreach ($value as $val) { //Loops through all of the checkboxes that have been selected
            $sql = "DELETE FROM users WHERE ID='$val'"; //Mysql code to delete from the databases where items have been selected

            if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) { //If a value has been deleted 
                echo "Record deleted successfully: "; 
            } else {
                echo "Error deleting record: " . $conn->error; //Prints error if value hasnt deleted
            }
            $conn->close();//Closes sql connection
            echo $val; //Echos values selected
            echo '</br>';
        }
    } else {
        $status = 0;
    }
    echo <<<END
    END;
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First and foremost, you're directly inserting posted data into a SQL query — and a `DELETE` query even! A malicious user can easily exploit this code to delete the entire contents of your database.

***ALWAYS*** escape user-submitted values that are used in SQL statements.

But to your direct question: you're calling `$conn->close()` immediately after executing the first `DELETE`. By the time you try to do the second, your server connection is already closed. Don't call `$conn->close()` until after your loop.

Comment: And also that `Delete` can be outside of loop using `IN` clause, probably improve performance?